# Equivalent of MySQL HEX / UNHEX function in SQL Server?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql, hex, type-conversion

Does SQL Server has an equivalent to the `HEX` and `UNHEX` MySQl functions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update 2022: This is outdated, read about `CONVERT()` together with binary types**.

What are you going to do?

Something like a script generation?

There might be better approaches for your issue, but you do not provide many details...

Not quite as slim but this would work

```
--This will show up like needed, but it will not be a string
SELECT CAST('abc' AS VARBINARY(MAX))

--this is the string equivalent
SELECT sys.fn_varbintohexstr(CAST('abc' AS VARBINARY(MAX)));

--This will turn the string equivalent back to varbinary
SELECT sys.fn_cdc_hexstrtobin('0x616263')

--And this will return the original string
SELECT CAST(sys.fn_cdc_hexstrtobin('0x616263') AS VARCHAR(MAX));
```

###One hint

If you deal with `UNICODE` you can check the changes if you set `N'abc'` instead of `'abc'` and in den final line you'd have to convert `'0x610062006300'` to `NVARCHAR`.

###Another hint

If you need this more often you might put this into an UDF, than it is as eays as with MySQL :-)